# How to serialize external types with atdgen?

Tags: ocaml

I am using Core and atdgen in my project.

I have the following record, that I want to serialize in JSON:

```
type person = {
  (* ... *)
  birth : Time.t;
  (* ... *)
}
```

Is it possible to tell in my atd file how to serialize `Time.t` values into strings (by calling `Time.to_string`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although @everiq's answer works, there is a much simpler method for converting JSON strings into custom types. At least for my case.

```
type time = string wrap <ocaml t="Core.Std.Time.t"
  wrap="Core.Std.Time.of_string" unwrap="Core.Std.Time.to_string">

type person = {
  (* ... *)
  birth : time;
  (* ... *)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap Time.t in a module like that:

```
type time <ocaml_json module="TimeWrapper" t="t"> = abstract
```

and then define your own read/write functions in TimeWrapper:

```
(* timeWrapper.mli *)
type t
val read_t : Yojson.Safe.lexer_state -> Lexing.lexbuf -> t
val write_t : Bi_outbuf.t -> t -> unit
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the `Bi_output` module? I can't find any doc about it.

Comment: Sorry, this is `Bi_outbuf` of cause. Just a typo. The module is provided by Yojson package. If you run atdgen on the declaration you can see this functions and signatures.